# json.loads is not working in python (from Automate the Boring Stuff ch. 14)

Tags: python, json

I tried entering the commands from chapter 14 of Automate the Boring Stuff but I got error messages.

```
>>> import json
>>> stringOfJsonData = '{"name": "Zophie", "isCat": true, "miceCaught": 0, "felineIQ": None}'
>>> jsonDataAsPythonValue = json.loads(stringOfJsonData)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    jsonDataAsPythonValue = json.loads(stringOfJsonData)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 64 (char 63)
```

Comment: You mixed up the python representation and the JSON representation. In JSON it must be `null` instead of `None`

Answer (score 2):

`None` is not a valid JSON value; in JSON the equivalent is `null`.